# I am new to PHP. Should I start with some framework or with my own authentication, session management and everything?

Tags: php, zend-framework, drupal

I am a c/c++ programmer. I have also worked on a website where I used drupal. While using drupal I made some custom modules using PHP. So I am familiar with PHP but not an expert as drupal provided basic functionalities like user-login, session management etc.

At this time I want to learn web development thoroughly. I am making one website too.

If I start with some framework like "Zend", I think, I dont get to know basics e.g. authentication techniques (this is my assumption). And I think I wont have much control over it.

If I start with my own then it will take much more time.

Should I use frameworks like "Zend" or start with scratch.

Comment: I'll write this here instead of an answer since this question doesn't belong here (it's too subjective, read the FAQ) and will be closed -- write your own. Understand everything first. Then you can offload the job of doing it all a second time for a second site by using a framework.

Comment: this depends on how "much more time" you have

Comment: How much experience have you got with C/C++, in years? Have you used libraries written by others in C and frameworks in C++?

Comment: I have 1 year experiance (in TCP, UDP). I have even modified the code for several open source web-servers to suit my needs. So I know the protocols and everything. Thats why I like to learn from very root .. But speed is also very important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally when compiling a web-application you're never developing everything from scratch but more like configuring a computer, you're reusing existing components.

So if you're looking for creating a web-app and learning all the details, I suggest you pick an open-source framework with an active development community and distributed version control so you can cook your own, profit from the masses, metric your code suggestion against the community and get review for your patches.

In short take [symfony2 which is available on github](https://github.com/symfony). It has an active development community, can be easily forked and is flexible enough that you can cook your own as well.

And you can learn by reading existing code btw. It's more important to "type" into your brain then to type into the computer. The computer should only be a tool that help you to get things done, normally your brain is capable enough to learn and understand things through imagination, only as last resort you should need to actually run a script to make the proof it works.

Comment: Thanks Hakre...  I think you're right about  "you can learn by reading existing code". I will start two projects: 1st using symfony and 2nd using basic functions.

Answer (score 2):

Really depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

**What you're really asking is if you should re-invent the wheel to understand how it works.**

If your ultimate goal is knowledge, do write your own modules. In fact you should do this, at least once just to grasp how it works.

If your ultimate goal is speed, performance and security, trust the community and go with tested software.

**Should you deploy a site using your home-made security modules that you've just wrote in order to understand security? Noooo!**

Answer (score 1):

IMO, if you want to learn web development thoroughly then you need to write your own code. If you use a framework that holds your hand and gives you lots of functionality then there'll be the temptation to not look at how it works in-depth.

You'll no doubt hit problems and get things wrong with your own framework and you can refer to the Zend, Code Ignitor, Cake PHP source to see how they do it if you need to.

Don't think there's any better was to learn than to build it yourself, find the problems and solve them in your own way.

Answer (score 0):

IAgree with @Frankie, after 5 years programming with PHP, now i have developed my own framework, you should really think about what you need right now, creating a project fast, or creating many projects in future and you are the guy who what's to do all by him self, because there are many frameworks out..

Answer (score 0):

> At this time I want to learn web development thoroughly.

Definitely, as others said, do it yourself. Besides, no framework is perfect, and there are at least tens of frameworks, those popular like Zend are just tip of the iceberg.

Learn php by using php, and then later deploy whatever suits your needs. From my experience, ready made functions or classes are far more helpful than using an entire framework that is not tailor-made to fit your needs.